# Better usage of require() in child module

Tags: javascript, node.js

after Googling around for a few hours on this topic to no avail, I'm hoping someone on here might be able to help clarify this piece of my project for me...

I have a project that has modules that it loads via require() and is able to name them explicitly as they are included in the package.json and have the "main" attribute in their package.json files themselves.
example: `require('submodule-name')`

The functionality works perfectly, but in each of these modules, I have to require the main file like so: `const mainModule = require('../../mainModuleName');`

This is so I can access functions and config variables that are attached to the main piece.

I'm wondering if there is a better way to `require()` this main module without a relative path, since my linter is complaining that the module doesnt exist when I lint the child-module repo on its own. Also, I'd like to employ the use of `npm link` for future development happiness.

Is there a way of doing this without relative paths? Maybe fix the `package.json` of the main project file?

UPDATE:
File/folder structure is as follows:

```
/
  mainModule.js
/node_modules
  childModule.js <- this requires the mainModule file with a relative path
/modules
  anotherChildModule.js <- same relative path requirement of mainModule
```

Comment: Can you show an example of current file / folder structure?

Comment: @James updated.

Comment: So if I understand you correctly, you have X project that includes Y & Z dependencies....which in turn reference X project? Sounds like a circular reference to me :/

Comment: VERY circular. and it works fine now... but there has to be a better way. @gaafar's answer seems the way to go

Comment: Yeah, I figured this was the case but wanted to ask for clarity before answering as I would have thought you would've  had problems trying to run this code. I've suggested an alternative solution to Gaafar's in that allows you to keep the modularity you seem to want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the problem is in the approach itself. Submodules should not depend on the main modules, as this reverses the dependencies (now the submodule depends on the parent module implementation). I recommend you avoid requiring parent directories, and pass the functions & config to the submodule when you require it instead.

eg: `const sub = require('submodule-name')(config)`

Comment: thats a very interesting approach, and would technically reduce the memory footprint of the entire core application, correct?

Comment: This was my immediate reaction too.  The sub-module should be passed the config with something like this rather than requiring it in.  I don't think this will reduce the memory footprint.  Requiring something a 2nd time just gets the previous module from the module cache - it does not use a meaningful amount of extra memory.

Comment: I'm not sure if memory footprint will change, but it's definitely linter friendly and will make your submodules easier to test & maintain

Comment: this ended up being the implementation I went with, since my config files may be changeable in the future.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative option, NPM supports importing local dependencies therefore you can create a "config" package that you could include in both your sub modules e.g.

**package.json**

```
"myconfig": "file:./common"
```

**childModule.js**

```
const config = require('myconfig')
```

Comment: oh wow, did not know about this feature... this is GOLD, dude.